# creating custom keyboard layout for textarea with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard, textarea

I want to create a keyboard site that have a keyboard(virtual with buttons) with a textarea.This project devide to two part:
**The first part** is typing with virtual keyboard on site that i created with buttons and javascript that i ended it and it works fine.
**The second part** is typing by real keyboard but with our custom language layuot on textarea.
I want to catch entered keys and then with checking shift or capslock state in my code add appropriate character(that exist in my custom layout) to textarea.
if i want to make it more simple,i want to get user keys in qwerty english keyboard and change it to other characters and then add to textarea just like custom keybaord layout.
we have three event on keys for working in javascript and jquery and they are **onkeypress** , **onkeydown** , **onkeyup**.
the problem of onkeyup is that i can't control the textarea when user holds a key and i can't use it.
My problem with onpressed and onkeydown is their defualt operation! They add qwerty english chars to textarea after my code and i can't find a way for disabling that operation.
For example we have a text like "abc" already in textarea and the cursor place is between b and c,the user want to type X(suppose that in my custom keyboard it is on g key place) in there when he presses g key i get cursor place and other stuffes and add X to string like "abXc" but then due to onpress default operation it add g after X and i can't do anything,i tryed to control it with keyup but the problem get bigger when user holds the key and i have "abXgXgXgXgXgXgXgXgXgc"!
How i can disable it from adding chars to textarea?

**Note** : Between keypress and keydown i preffer to use keypress becuase i can't detect shift and capslock and use my own way in code for dealing with shifted state and capslock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.preventDefault()` to stop the default behaviour of the event from happening. This (somewhat silly) example illustrates how you can disable the `a` button for a text input or textarea with ID `demo`:

```
$(function() {

    $("#demo").keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.which == 97) {
            //The user pressed "a".
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

What you want to do is first check which key was pressed (using `event.which`), then add your replacement for that key to the textarea, and finally just call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the character the user actually typed from being outputted.

Since it's the `onkeypress` event that outputs the character, you must use it and not `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` if you want to use this approach.

- [Documentation on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
- [Documentation on W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: Thanks , It's exactly what i want.

Comment: I think we can use onkeydown after overriding the onkeypress with just a event.preventDefault(); in it.